# How to make the text clickable in Jtextpane?

Tags: jtextpane, clickable

Basically I am implementing a search function in an ontology. So when I enter a keyword to search, it is searched in the ontology and the corresponding results are displayed in JTextpane. Now what I want is when user click certain terms in that result, it should again perform the same search function for that term as keyword and display it in JTextpane . So how can I make some text in JTextpane clickable and implement a function on clicking it? Eg :

For the keyword, cataract, it displays something like this
//description

cataract  is a disease of Opthalmology
//description

so when I click Opthalmology, then i should be able to again implement the search for Opthalmology.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom attribute to the clickable keywords (or detect the keywords by click using `viewToModel` to convert clicked point to `Document's` offset).

Then do your search and insert content.

May be you could provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to show what you have and tell what you would like to achieve.

Comment: This is what I'm searching the whole internet... @StanislavL can you please explain it clearly.. I really need your help

Comment: @Gogo post a separate question with your particular needs. It's better to answer rather than add a common description.

Comment: thanks for your reply... Can you please check on it?